# Display busyindicator in wpf application

Tags: wpf, multithreading, busyindicator

I have a BusyIndicator from the wpf extended toolkit and I'm running a function that takes a while to complete.  If I run the time consuming task in a separate thread, I get a NotSupportedException because I'm attemping to insert objects into an ObservableCollection from that different thread.  I don't really want to spend a lot of time refactoring the code, if possible... Is there a way that I can set the visibility of the indicator in a separate thread instead?

**EDIT**

```
ThreadStart start = delegate()
  {
      System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
          {
              IsBusy = true;
          }));
   };

new Thread(start).Start();                                
longRunningFunction();
```

This did not work for me either.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide you with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) for things like that. e.g.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    _indicator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}));
```

This will cause the code to be run on the UI-Thread.

There is more info (including how to "properly" do this, with [`CheckAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess.aspx) and such) on it in the [threading model reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx).

Comment: This didn't work... the busy indicator doesn't become visible:
    `System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
       {
           IsBusy = true;
       }));
    functionThatTakesForever();
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
       {
           IsBusy = false;
       }));`

Would the fact that I'm performing these operations in the ViewModel rather than in the codebehind have any effect on the way it behaves?

Comment: @drowned: You are running that on a different thread, right? If you do not the UI will still block. Use the dispatcher in the background thread whenever you need to access elements owned by the UI-thread, including your ObservableCollection.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood... I'll update my question to reflect what I attempted to do.

Comment: The long running function needs to be executed on the background thread as well of course. Otherwise the whole thing is pointless, if you were just to set the IsBusy you would not need a thread for that.

Comment: But when I do that, I get the exception upon attempting to insert into the collection

Comment: @drowned: As i said, also use the Dispatcher when accessing the collection.

Comment: Ok I missed that part.  Both of these answers work in this way, but I think I worded my question poorly.  I still want the UI to be blocked while the long running task is processing, I just need to show a message before it starts, stating that the system is loading.  These solutions allow the user to interact with the window while it's happening.

Comment: @drowned: You could use a popup window which can contain the indicator, if you show it via ShowDialog the no interaction with the main window will be possible until it is closed, you then can close it after your long-running method is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access UI controls from a background worker.  What you normally do is set the IsBusy to true before you call BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAync(), then in the BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted event handler you would set the IsBusy to false.  Seomthing like:

```
Backgroundworker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += ...
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
{
     IsBusy = false;
};
IsBusy = true;
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

You can use the Dispatcher to add items to your ObservableCollection while in the DoWork event hanlder.

**EDIT**: Here is the complete solution

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //on UI thread
        ObservableCollection<string> collection;

        ThreadStart start = delegate()
        {
            List<string> items = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
            {
                items.Add(String.Format("Item {0}", i));
            }

            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                //propogate items to UI
                collection = new ObservableCollection<string>(items);
                //hide indicator
                _indicator.IsBusy = false;
            }));
        };
        //show indicator before calling start
        _indicator.IsBusy = true;
        new Thread(start).Start();      
    }
```

Comment: This is the first thing I tried.  I get the same exception when trying to insert into a collection.

Comment: @H.B. The concepts is the same even if you aren't using the BackgroundWorker.